# How do you mock ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-router

I'm learning Angular and I want to do tests, but I'm stuck. I've got a function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
        this.SomethingService.getSomething(params.get('id')))
        .subscribe(something => {
            this.something = something;
            this.doSomethingElse();
    });
}
```

where

```
route: ActivatedRoute
```

and I want to test it but I don't know how to mock ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 55):

A simple way to mock `ActivatedRoute` is this one:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponenToTest],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            params: Observable.from([{id: 1}]),
          },
        },
      ]
    });
```

Then in your test it will be available and your function should work with this (at least the ActivatedRoute part)

You can get it with `TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute)` in your `it` functions if you want to stock it in a variable.

Don't forget to import Observable from `rxjs/Rx` and not from `rxjs/Observable`

Comment: This doesn't work because the OP is using `paramMap` and not `params`.

Comment: Instead of importing observable from rxjs/Rx, I used `of([{id: 1}])`. (`import { of } from 'rxjs';`)

Comment: Maybe someone will find this useful. I needed to easily set the activatedRoute paramsMap and URL between tests. https://gist.github.com/rossholdway/89a50d466d55bbed8d402c2d81f44741 provides an easy way to do this by calling `route.set('categories/:slug', {slug: 'featured'});`. Params are optional.

Comment: For `paramMap`: `useValue: { paramMap: of(convertToParamMap({id: 1})) },`

Comment: Adding to what Ross says above. You can get the activated route mock/stub and add the the params object and replay subject to solve your problem (just follow the pattern for paramMap. Alternatively, download the finished one from here https://github.com/adrobson/activatedroutestub. Then just before you create the component in your test, call mockActivatedRoute.set and pass in your params for the route.

Comment: For snapshot.paramMap reference this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49921090/7660196

Answer (score 42):

For anyone interested on how to properly do it with multiple properties, this is the way you define your mock class:

```
import { convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class ActivatedRouteMock {
    public paramMap = Observable.of(convertToParamMap({ 
        testId: 'abc123',
        anotherId: 'd31e8b48-7309-4c83-9884-4142efdf7271',          
    }));
}
```

This way you can subscribe to your `paramMap` and retrieve multiple values - in this case `testId` and `anotherId`.

Comment: Argument of type 'ActivatedRouteMock' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActivatedRoute'.
  Type 'ActivatedRouteMock' is missing the following properties from type 'ActivatedRoute': url, params, queryParams, fragment, and 11 more

Comment: @lohiarahul There must be some kind of type check forcing on your end.

Comment: how does one set the desired paramID in the specific test? like lets say one test needs testId and the other needs anotherId? @AndriusNaruševičius

Answer (score 20):

Modifying Andrus' answer above . . .

For RxJS 6+:

```
import { convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { of } from 'rxjs';


export class ActivatedRouteMock {
    public paramMap = of(convertToParamMap({ 
        testId: 'abc123',
        anotherId: 'd31e8b48-7309-4c83-9884-4142efdf7271',          
    }));
}
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html

Comment: Why was `Observable` import left then?

Comment: my mistake, removed it . . .

Comment: Argument of type 'ActivatedRouteMock' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActivatedRoute'.
  Type 'ActivatedRouteMock' is missing the following properties from type 'ActivatedRoute': url, params, queryParams, fragment, and 11 more

Answer (score 19):

I was facing the same problem using `paramMap` instead of `params`.  This got it working for me, at least for the simplest case:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { ComponentToTest } from './component-to-test.component';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ComponentToTest],
  providers: [
    { 
        provide: ActivatedRoute, 
        useValue: {
            paramMap: Observable.of({ get: (key) => 'value' })
        }
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had to create a new class to handle this type of test, this class will allow you to handle snapshot, queryParams, and params.

```
import { Params } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class MockActivatedRoute {
  private innerTestParams?: any;
  private subject?: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.testParams);

  params = this.subject.asObservable();
  queryParams = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor(params?: Params) {
    if (params) {
      this.testParams = params;
    } else {
      this.testParams = {};
    }
  }

  get testParams() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  set testParams(params: {}) {
    this.innerTestParams = params;
    this.subject.next(params);
  }

  get snapshot() {
    return { params: this.testParams, queryParams: this.testParams };
  }
}
```

this is how the test should look

```
import { MockActivatedRoute } from './mock-active-router';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let activatedRouteStub: MockActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    activatedRouteStub = new MockActivatedRoute();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteStub }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should change params', () => {
    expect(component.myparam).toBeUndefined();
    expect(component.paramTwo).toBeUndefined();

    activatedRouteStub.testParams = {
      myparam: 'value',
      paramTwo: 1
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.myparam).toEqual('value');
    expect(component.paramTwo).toEqual(1);
  });
```

https://gist.github.com/dvaJi/cf552bbe6725535955f7a5eeb92d7d2e

Comment: This enabled me to test several different params. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem since forever and I find out that this way it works as I want. No need to spy on the get for me for example.

Given:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.some = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('some') === 'some';
  this.else = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('else');
}
```

Then:

```js
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let component: SomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;

  let activatedRouteSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    activatedRouteSpy = {
      snapshot: {
        paramMap: convertToParamMap({
          some: 'some',
          else: 'else',
        })
      }
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteSpy },
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should load correct data (original stuff)', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick(2000);
    
    // ... do your checks ...
  }));

  it('should load correct data (different stuff)', fakeAsync(() => {
    activatedRouteSpy.snapshot.paramMap = convertToParamMap({
      some: 'some',
      else: null,
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick(2000);

    // ... do your checks ...
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In recent Angular versions, a project's `aot` setting will be on by default (for better compile-time type checking). If this is the case with your project, then you probably need to at least stub out all the properties of ActivatedRoute and ActivatedRouteSnapshot. Something like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Type } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { MockPlatformLocation } from '@angular/common/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Params, ParamMap, convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { Hero } from '../hero';


export class MockActivatedRouteSnapshot implements ActivatedRouteSnapshot {
  private innerTestParams?: Params;

  constructor(params?: Params) {
    if (params) {
      this.testParams = params;
    } else {
      this.testParams = null;
    }
  }

  private get testParams() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  private set testParams(params: Params) {
    this.innerTestParams = params;
  }

  get paramMap() {
    return convertToParamMap(this.testParams);
  }

  get queryParamMap() {
    return this.paramMap;
  }

  get url() {
    return null;
  }

  get fragment() {
    return null;
  }

  get data() {
    return null;
  }

  get outlet() {
    return null;
  }

  get params() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  get queryParams() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  get component() {
    return null;
  }

  get routeConfig() {
    return null;
  }

  get root() {
    return null;
  }

  get parent() {
    return null;
  }

  get firstChild() {
    return null;
  }

  get children() {
    return null;
  }

  get pathFromRoot() {
    return null;
  }
}


export class MockActivatedRoute implements ActivatedRoute {
  private innerTestParams?: Params;
  private subject?: BehaviorSubject<Params> = new BehaviorSubject(this.testParams);
  private paramMapSubject?: BehaviorSubject<ParamMap> = new BehaviorSubject(convertToParamMap(this.testParams));

  constructor(params?: Params) {
    if (params) {
      this.testParams = params;
    } else {
      this.testParams = null;
    }
  }

  private get testParams() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  private set testParams(params: Params) {
    this.innerTestParams = params;
    this.subject.next(params);
    this.paramMapSubject.next(convertToParamMap(params));
  }

  get snapshot() {
    return new MockActivatedRouteSnapshot(this.testParams);
  }

  get params() {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  get queryParams() {
    return this.params;
  }

  get paramMap() {
    return this.paramMapSubject.asObservable();
  }

  get queryParamMap() {
    return this.paramMap;
  }

  get url() {
    return null;
  }

  get fragment() {
    return null;
  }

  get data() {
    return null;
  }

  get outlet() {
    return null;
  }

  get component() {
    return null;
  }

  get routeConfig() {
    return null;
  }

  get root() {
    return null;
  }

  get parent() {
    return null;
  }

  get firstChild() {
    return null;
  }

  get children() {
    return null;
  }

  get pathFromRoot() {
    return null;
  }
}


describe('HeroDetailComponent', () => {
  let component: HeroDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeroDetailComponent>;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let routeMock: MockActivatedRoute;
  let initialMockParams: Params;
  let locationMock: MockPlatformLocation;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    initialMockParams = {id: 11};
    routeMock = new MockActivatedRoute(initialMockParams);
    locationMock = new MockPlatformLocation;
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ HeroDetailComponent ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routeMock,
        },
        {
          provide: Location, useValue: locationMock,
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroDetailComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    httpMock = TestBed.inject<HttpTestingController>(HttpTestingController as Type<HttpTestingController>);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

    const dummyHero: Hero = { id: 11, name: 'dummyHero' };
    const req = httpMock.expectOne('api/details/11');
    req.flush(dummyHero);
  });
});
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63414641/5067822).

Answer (score 4):

I use RxJS Subject instead of Observable for the paramMap. This way I can trigger the paramMap to emit new values during testing.

The ActivatedRoute is mocked directly in the providers-section of Testbed config:

```
providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { paramMap: new Subject() } }]
```

Then, i get the activated route from the testbed:

```
activatedRoute = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
```

And trigger the paramMap to emit new values whenever required in the test procedure:

```
activatedRoute.paramMap.next({ get: (key: string) => 'value1'});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Create mock class first:**

```
import { Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class ActivatedRouteMock {
  snapshot: {
    params: Params;
  };

  paramMap: Observable<Params>;

  constructor(params: Params) {
    const extendedParams = {
      ...params,
      get(paramName: string) {
        return params[paramName];
      }
    };
    this.snapshot = {
      params: extendedParams
    };
    this.paramMap = of(extendedParams);
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: new ActivatedRouteMock({ deliveryId: 'test' })
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: thanks! worked great for me for mocking activatedRoute for storybook story!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to run tests with a test using `ActivatedRoute` is to mock it using `BehaviorSubjects` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject).

In your test bed setup code:

```js
let activatedRouteMock = {
  queryMap: new BehaviorSubject<ParamMap>(
    convertToParamMap({ paramName: 'default value' })
  )
};

await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock }
      ],
      // ..rest of test bed 
    }).compileComponents();

// ...rest of setupcode
```

Then, test without supplying custom parameter

```js
it('some test', () => {
   // run your test code that expects default parameters
})
```

Then, test with special parameters

```js
it('some other test', () => {
  activatedRouteMock.queryMap.next(convertToParamMap({ paramName: 'special value' }));

  // ...test that your component does what it's supposed to
});
```

This can obviously be constructed into a mock class that extends `ActivatedRoute`, or you can do a similar setup for `params` or `queryParams` instead of `paramMap`.

Comment: I really like this approach as you can have separate tests in the same spec with different params. I had to tweak the above from queryMap to paramMap for my scenario but otherwise it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to mock a param or queryParam on ActivatedRoute.

To mock a param: 'http:://localhost/web/param'

```
beforeEach(async () => {

const params = new BehaviorSubject({ param: 'valueOf' });
const activatedRoute = { params, snapshot: { params } };
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [Component],
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  providers: [
    someproviders...,
    {
      provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute
    }
  ]
})
  .compileComponents();
```

});

this allow to change in distinct test on your file spec.ts the value of 'param'. To do this:

```
const params = new BehaviorSubject({ param: 'newValueOf' });
component['activeRoute'].params = params; //activeRoute is the public property in the constructor that instances ActivatedRoute
```

In this example, the url with the mock of 'param' is: 'http:://localhost/web/valueOf'

To queryParams: 'http:://localhost/web?queryParam=some'

do this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
const queryParams = new BehaviorSubject({ queryParam: 'valueOf' });
const activatedRoute = { queryParams, snapshot: { queryParams: queryParams.value } };
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ Component ],
  providers: [
    someproviders...,
    {
      provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute
    }
  ],
  imports: [RouterTestingModule]
})
.compileComponents();
```

});

In this case, to set queryParams, you have to add .value.