# Angular testing ngOnInit with sevice calls

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am learning unit testing in Angular using jasmine. I have a component in which the `ngOnInit()` method has certain service calls. Below is my `ngOnInit()` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.componentInteractionService.resetCurrentMenu();
    this.router.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.currentContentUrl = params.get("currentContentUrl");
      let tmp = params.get("contentTitle");
      this.contentSubstitle = params.get("contentSubtitle");
      if (tmp == undefined) {
        let url = this.currentContentUrl;
        this.contentTitle = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length);
      } 
      else {
        this.contentTitle = tmp;
      }
    });
  }
```

So how should I test so that all the lines of the `ngOnInit()` method are covered? I mean I need full code coverage.
In my `spec.ts`:

```
it('should call all methods in ngOnInit', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    .......
    .......
  });
```

What should I write after `component.ngOnInit();`? Please help. I can test the first line which is:
`this.componentInteractionService.resetCurrentMenu();`
But how to test the rest of the lines?

Comment: You can mock the `paramMap` to return the values you require. Return a value such that the `if` block is covered and you can assert `contentTitle`, `contentSubtitle` and `currentContentUrl` and the same for the `else` block. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917883/how-do-you-mock-activatedroute That's how you mock paramMap and for you you will need to mock `params.get` as well.

Comment: @AliF50 The if condition requires tmp to be undefined....but tmp is a let variable. How to set tmp to be undefined?

Comment: But `tmp` gets set from `params.get('contentTitle')` and you should have control of this in your tests.

Comment: @DhritimanTamuliSaikia: would you mind letting me know any comments on my answer ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek Sorry for the late reply...But what happened is that I am asked to do the testing using Jest now...So I am facing a couple of other issues handling Jest...Didn't check whether your code is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponenToTest],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            paramMap: of([
             {currentContentUrl: 'ccu/tt'}
             {contentSubtitle: 'cs'},
             {contentTitle: 'ct'}
             ]),
          },
        },
      ]
    });

   it('should call all methods in ngOnInit', () => {
      spyOn(component.componentInteractionService,'resetCurrentMenu')
              .and.returnValue('');
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.currentContentUrl).toBe('ccu/tt');
      // similar for component.contentSubstitle for 'cs'
      // similar for component.contentTitle for 'ct'
    });

   it('should set in 'contentTitle' accordingly in ngOnInit', () => {
      component.route.paramMap = of([
             {currentContentUrl: 'ccu/tt'}
             {contentSubtitle: 'cs'}
             ])
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.currentContentUrl).toBe('ccu/tt');
      // similar for component.contentSubstitle for 'cs'
      // similar for component.contentTitle for 'tt' 
    });
```

Let me know if the mocking works